# need to add smtp to the jquery form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database, smtp

this form is sending data to database but i need the query should also go to the two other ids someone said use smtp but i don't know how and where to add smtp in this form. please help thanks in advance

```html
<?php
  // Attention! Please read the following.
  // It is important you do not edit pieces of code that aren't tagged as a configurable options identified by the following:

  // Configuration option.

  // Each option that is easily editable has a modified example given.


  $error   = '';
  $name   = '';
  $email   = '';
        $organisation = '';
  $phone   = ''; 
  $subject  = '';
  $comments  = '';
  //$verify  = '';

  if(isset($_POST['contactus'])) {

  $name    = $_POST['name'];
  $email    = $_POST['email'];
        $organisation  = $_POST['name'];
  $phone    = $_POST['phone']; 
  $subject   = $_POST['subject'];
  $comments   = $_POST['comments'];
  //$verify  = $_POST['verify'];


$servername = "localhost";
 $username = "auweb";
 $password = "auw3b";
 $dbname = "auweb";
 $useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
 $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  
 //echo $msg;
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
  
} 
$sql="";
 if(empty($name)||empty($phone)||empty($email)||empty($subject)||empty($comments)){
   $sql = "INSERT INTO `aki_logs` (`ts`, `name`, `email`, `phone`, `state`, `course`, `useragent`, `ip`, `status`)VALUES (now(), '$name', '$email', '$phone', '$comments', '$subject', '$useragent', '$ip', 'Error');";
  
  //echo 'Please enter all the data';
 
  
  header('location:index.php');
  
 }
 else{
  
   $sql = "INSERT INTO `aki_logs` (`ts`, `name`, `email`, `phone`, `state`, `course`, `useragent`, `ip`, `status`)VALUES (now(), '$name', '$email', '$phone', '$comments', '$subject', '$useragent', '$ip', 'Success');";
  
  
 }
  
 $conn->query($sql);
 $conn->close();
 //$to="admissions2@ansaluniversity.edu.in,siddhartha@digidarts.com";
 //$to='admissions2@ansaluniversity.edu.in';


@date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
@session_start();
unset($_POST['formname']); unset($_POST['submit']);
$csv = implode('","', $_POST);
$csv = '"'.date("d-m-Y").'","'. date("H:i:s") .'","' . $csv . '"' . "\r\n";
$file = '../../data/'. basename( __DIR__ ) .'.csv';
@file_put_contents($file, $csv, FILE_APPEND);
  
  

  // Configuration option.
  // You may change the error messages below.
  // e.g. $error = 'Attention! This is a customised error message!';

  if(trim($name) == '') {
   $error = '<div class="error_message">Attention! You must enter your name.</div>';
  } else if(trim($email) == '') {
   $error = '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid email address.</div>';

  // Configuration option.
  // Remove the // tags below to active phone number.
  } else if(!is_numeric($phone)) {
  // $error = '<div class="error_message">Attention! Phone number can only contain digits.</div>';

  } else if(!isEmail($email)) {
   $error = '<div class="error_message">Attention! You have enter an invalid e-mail address, try again.</div>';
  }

  if(trim($organisation) == '') {
   $error = '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a subject.</div>';
  } else if(trim($comments) == '') {
   $error = '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter your message.</div>';
  }// else if(trim($verify) == '') {
  // $error = '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter the verification number.</div>';
  //} else if(trim($verify) != '4') {
  // $error = '<div class="error_message">Attention! The verification number you entered is incorrect.</div>';
  //}

  if($error == '') {

   if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
   }


  // Configuration option.
  // Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
  // Example $address = "";

  $address = "mk@gmail.com, mk2@gmail.com";


  // Configuration option.
  // i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

  // Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

  $e_organisation = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';


  // Configuration option.
  // You can change this if you feel that you need to.
  // Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

  $e_body = "You have been contacted by $name with regards to $organisation, their additional message is as follows.\r\n\n";
  $e_content = "\"$comments\"\r\n\n";

  // Configuration option.
  // RIf you active phone number, swap the tags of $e-reply below to include phone number.
  $e_reply = "You can contact $name via email, $email or via phone $phone";
  //$e_reply = "You can contact $name via email, $email";

  $msg = $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply;

  if(mail($address, $e_organisation, $msg, "From: 'enquiry@gmail.com'\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n"))
  {
   // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

    echo "<div id='succsess_page'>";
    echo "<h1>Email Sent Successfully.</h1>";
    echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
    echo "</div>";
   } else echo "Error. Mail not sent";

  }
 }

  if(!isset($_POST['contactus']) || $error != '') // Do not edit.
  {
?>

   <?php echo $error; ?>

   <fieldset>

   <legend>Please fill in the following form to contact us</legend>

   <form method="post" action="#succsess_page">
            
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">

   <label for=name accesskey=U><span class="required">*</span> Your Name</label>
   <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />

   <br />
   <label for=email accesskey=E><span class="required">*</span> Email</label>
   <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />

   <br />
    
   <label for=phone accesskey=P><span class="required">*</span> Phone</label>
   <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="30" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" />

  </div><!--COL-FORM HALF-->
        
        <div class="col-md-6">
         
   <label for=subject accesskey=S><span class="required">*</span> Subject</label>
   <select name="subject" id="subject">
    
    <option value="B. A. (Hons) - Liberal Arts">B. A. (Hons) - Liberal Arts</option>
    
   </select>

   <br />
            
   <label for=comments accesskey=C><span class="required">*</span> Query</label>
   <textarea name="comments" cols="30" rows="3" id="comments"><?php echo $comments; ?></textarea>

   <hr />

   <!--<p><span class="required">*</span> Are you human?</p>

   <label for=verify accesskey=V>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3 + 1 =</label>
   <input name="verify" type="text" id="verify" size="4" value="<?php echo $verify; ?>" /><br /><br />-->

   <input name="contactus" type="submit" class="submit" id="contactus" value="Submit" />
         
        </div>
   </div>
           

   </form>
   </fieldset>

<?php }

function isEmail($email) { // Email address verification, do not edit.
return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}
?>
```

Comment: you mean the mail should be send over smtp?

Comment: This is horrible code... it is full of security issues!

Comment: Your question is completely unclear. Don't get this wrong, but it reads as if you have no idea what you are actually doing, you use terms in contexts that do not make sense... `smtp` is a protocol to send email messages, I fail to see the connection here. And how should "a query go to two other ids"?

Comment: i am sorry if i written wrong.
this form is unable to send query to address 1 and address 2 but its sending query to database now i don't know whats wrong in this client asking me to add smtp to it can any other solution other  than smtp

Comment: http://www.9lessons.info/2009/10/send-mail-using-smtp-and-php.html
i found this can i go with this

Answer (score 0):

If you should send an email after form submitting, you can use the php "mail()" function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). 
Or, if you wanna use SMTP protocol you should integrate in your project a plugins like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). See ya!